# Launch spring boot mvc test from custom testng framework

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, testng, spring-test

Where I'm working one of our customer required to use a custom test framework written using testng that allows to handle different parameters and test iterations using excel files.

This framework uses a main class to handle all the tests, lets call it TestManager.

This TestManager defines all the @Before and @After operations and has a method called exec() which is annotated as @Test.

This method is used to call the different components required from the test, these components are java classes that implements a single method exec() containing the logic of the single component.

```
    public class TestManager {
        // ... Before, After methods
    
        @Test(
                dataProvider = "..."
        )
        public void exec(Parameter[] inParameter) {
            // load parameters...
            foreach component:
                component.exec()
        }
    }
```

```
    public class ComponentXYZ {
        public void exec() {
        // load input params
        // Call a microservice and get results, find value on db, selenium operations...
        // unload output params for next components
        }
    }
```

This framework was designed to be used with selenium, or to test microservices using some http request library and is contained in a standalone module.

So my project has:

- A spring boot module
- A test module which (in my idea) should have a dependency over the spring boot module

Given this situation do you think it could be possible to use WebMvcTest to perform integration tests while using this custom framework?

I've been trying for a while but I'm always getting errors or I'm not able to @Autowire MockMvc, I can't seem to start a minimal spring boot instance directly from this test framework...

I don't think running my spring boot app and calling the microservices using http is the correct way to test but at this moment is the only thing it's working.

Comment: Sounds like you are basically trying to leverage e2e automation tests for your integration tests. If you would like to use the tests on an as is basis then you should be spawning your springboot app in a docker container and then have these tests point at it. You can perhaps add a custom listener that will be able to spawn your micro service app before the tests kick in and then work with it.

Comment: Since I can't access the production environment and set up a docker container I've managed to do something similar in a pretty bruteforced way, I'm running the application in the generate-test-resources phase and stopping it just right after tests.

Unfortunately the module is using surefire, so I can't use the pre-integration and post-integration phase